# Выдает ошибку java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

Вот код метода:

```
 @Override
    public void accountImport(String fileName, AccountDto accountDto) {
        try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, false))

        {
            Integer id = accountDto.getId();
            String stId= id.toString();

            Long number = accountDto.getNumber();
            String stNumber = number.toString();

            String date = accountDto.getDate();

            String beneficiary = accountDto.getBeneficiary();

            String comment = accountDto.getComment();

            Long amount = accountDto.getAmount();
            String stAmount = amount.toString();

            String currency = accountDto.getCurrency();

            String finall = stId+","+stNumber+","+date+","+beneficiary+","+comment+","+stAmount+","+currency;
            for (int i = 0; i < finall.length(); i++)
                writer.write(finall.charAt(i));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw  new ValidateException("ERROR");
        }

    }
```

Вот код контроллера:

```
@PostMapping("/import")
    public  ResponseEntity importAccount(@RequestParam(name = "fileName",required = false) String fileName, @RequestBody AccountDto accountDto){
        accountServiceImport.accountImport(fileName,accountDto);
        return  new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Вот запрос в Postman:

```
{
    "fileName": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\task\\text.csv",
  "account":{
    "id": 0,
    "number": 84822,
    "date": "2022-04-06  22:58 ",
    "beneficiary": "Bob",
    "comment": "For",
    "amount": 8482200,
    "currency": "USA"
    }
    
        
}
```

Comment: Можно увидеть логи?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предположить, что вы неправильно пользуетесь постманом (RequestParam надо передавать в другой вкладке). Из-за этого не передается имя файла и FileWriter не может его открыть. Ниже я привел пример скриншотов, как надо сформулировать ваш запрос в Postman.

[image: для параметров запросов]

[image: для тела запроса]

P.S В логе, который вы скинули написано, что в запросе присутствуют символы, которые нельзя использовать. Чтобы разрешить их использование, добавьте в файл конфигурации application.yaml следующие строки:

```yaml
server:
    relaxed-query-chars: \
```

Похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287922/the-valid-characters-are-defined-in-rfc-7230-and-rfc-3986

Также можете попробовать вместо url ввести закодированный вариан строки: `C%3A%5C%5CUsers%5C%5CAdmin%5C%5CDocuments%5C%5Ctask%5C%5Ctext.csv`.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [&#47;account&#47;import?fileName=C:\\Users\Admin\\Documents\\task\\text.csv ]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Comment: Исправил ответ.